# extracting more information from webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have written a code to extract the mobile models from the following website

"http://www.kart123.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=659eb948-c365-492c-99ef-59bd9f0427c6"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.kart123.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=659eb948-c365-492c-99ef-59bd9f0427c6")
elem=[]
elem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="pu-title fk-font-13"]')
for e in elem:
 print e.text
```

Everything is working fine but the problem arises at the end of the page. It is showing the contents of the first page only.Please could you help me what can I do in order to get all the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you on your way, I would use while loops using sleep to get all the page loaded before getting the information from the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?   p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=659eb948-c365-492c-99ef-59bd9f0427c6")
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # scroll to bottom of page
    time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="show-more-results"]').click() # click load more  button, needs to be done until you reach the end.
elem=[]
elem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="pu-title fk-font-13"]')
for e in elem:
   print e.text
```

Comment: everything else is fine, but click() is not responding. Any other solutions ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It doesnot loads anything whenever we are required to click anything. It loads till the page it automatically loads without any need to click.

Comment: does the " show more results" button show? How many pages do you want to see?

Comment: I want to see all the pages, but the click() button doesnt work even once

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got my answer. I need to put a time sleep after click button :) Thanks a lot.:D

Comment: I was just writing that! Page has to load fully so you need to sleep to allow the button to be visible

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is going to be a major hack but here goes... The site gets more phones as you scroll down by hitting an ajax script giving you 20 more each time. The script its hitting is this:

[http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p[]=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=tyy%2C4io&start=1&ref=8aef4a5f-3429-45c9-8b0e-41b05a9e7d28&ajax=true](http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5b%5d=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=tyy%2C4io&start=1&ref=8aef4a5f-3429-45c9-8b0e-41b05a9e7d28&ajax=true)

Notice the start parameter you can hack this into what you want with

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

num = 1
while num <=2450:
    """
    This condition will need to be updated to the maximum number
    of models you're interested in (or if you're feeling brave try to extract
    this from the top of the page)
    """
    driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p[]=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=tyy%2C4io&start=%f&ref=8aef4a5f-3429-45c9-8b0e-41b05a9e7d28&ajax=true" % num)
    elem=[]
    elem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="pu-title fk-font-13"]')
    for e in elem:
        print e.text
    num += 20
```

You'll be making 127 get requests so this will be quite slow...

Answer (score 0):

You can get full source of the page and do all the analysis based on it:

```
page_text = driver.page_source
```

The page shall contain current content including whatever was generated by JavaScript. Be carefull to get this content at the moment, all the rendering is completed (you may e.g. wait for presence of some string, which gets rendered at the end).

Comment: Models are loaded in 20 at a time by an ajax script as you scroll so this won't work. (there are 2450 models so it would be nuts to have them all loaded at once!)